# Recover Oracle system01.dbf

Tags: oracle, database-administration, recover

When i trying to start oracle db, it says

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01113: file 1 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/u01/oradata/oracle/system01.dbf'
```

When I trying to recover using redo logs, i've got

```
SQL> recover database using backup controlfile;
ORA-00279: change 4925223599 generated at 02/05/2018 10:24:32 needed for thread
1
ORA-00289: suggestion :
/mnt/backup/oracle/ORACLE/archivelog/2018_02_05/o1_mf_1_186975_%u_.arc
ORA-00280: change 4925223599 for thread 1 is in sequence #186975


Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}
/u01/oradata/oracle/redo01.log
ORA-00310: archived log contains sequence 186973; sequence 1
86975 required
ORA-00334: archived log: '/u01/oradata/oracle/redo01.log'
```

So, in the redo log i only have 186973 sequence. How can i revert all the oracle world to 186973 sequence and forget about next 2 seqs? I need to bring up the db anyhow and some chunk of last data i can lose.

Comment: have you tried `ALTER SYSTEM ARCHIVE LOG ALL`?

Comment: `ORA-01649: operation not allowed with a backup control file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by running

```
recover automatic database;
```

Yeah! That simple, thank you all